# How to save the MUI-X DataGrid state on changes occuring after the initial state load?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mui-x-data-grid, mui-x

I am currently implementing a grid state persistence in localStorage so that any user that did previous changes in the grid state will get it back when revisiting:

Targeted changes to save

- columns order/sizing/visibility
- search
- sorting

I am trying to use the DataGridPremium onStateChange event, although the event is fired when the state is initialize. I don't want that since I don't want to save the state when the user did not no change anything to the grid.

**Is there a way that I could skip the initialState change event?**

May be an event I could bind to that would tell me the grid finished loading his initialState and save a component state "gridInitialized".

Here's a snippet of my grid:

```
<DataGridPremium
    initialState={{
        ...initialState,
        sorting: {
            // Sort first column by default.
            sortModel: [{ field: columns[0].field, sort: 'asc' }],
            ...initialState?.sorting,
        },
    }}
    onStateChange={handleStateChangeEvent}
    { ...otherProps }
 />
```

And to my handleStateChangeEvent function:

```
const handleStateChangeEvent: GridEventListener<'stateChange'> = useCallback(() => {

  // if (!gridInitialized) return;  // ???

  saveState(
    {
      ...apiRef.current.exportState(),
      preferencePanel: { open: false },
    },
    STATE_KEY
  );
}, [STATE_KEY, apiRef]);
```

I tried to only bind on specific DataGridPremium changeEvent, but I missed changes I wanted to capture.

For instance:

```
<DataGridPremium
    initialState={{
        ...initialState,
        sorting: {
            // Sort first column by default.
            sortModel: [{ field: columns[0].field, sort: 'asc' }],
            ...initialState?.sorting,
        },
    }}
    onColumnOrderChange={handleEvent}
    onColumnWidthChange={handleEvent}
    onPreferencePanelClose={handleEvent}
    { ...otherProps }
 />
```

and

```
  // Save state to local storage
  const handleEvent: GridEventListener<
    'columnOrderChange' | 'columnWidthChange' | 'preferencePanelClose'
  > = useCallback(
    () => {
      saveState(
        {
          ...apiRef.current.exportState(),
          preferencePanel: { open: false },
        },
        STATE_KEY
      );
    },
    [STATE_KEY, apiRef]
  );
```

Thank you

Comment: Did you solve your issue? i am struggling in something not so different, can you help me ?